# Assertion Error in Dialog manipulation

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog, modal-dialog

The title is pretty weak, but I will try to explain here. I am working on an MFC Application. When a button is clicked, a new dialog is created, some strings are added to a `ComboBox` from that second dialog, and then the dialog is showed. The code is depicted below. Combo1 is a `CComboBox` variable defined in the Class1.h file. The problem is that when I try to call the `dlg.Foo()` method, the program gives me a `Debug Assertion Error`. The error hits on the `AddString` line, furthermore in the `afxwin2.inl` file, in this line of code:

```
{ ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd)); return (int)::SendMessage(m_hWnd, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)lpszString); }
```

---

```
CClass1 dlg = new CClass1(this);
dlg.Foo();
dlg.DoModal();
```

---

```
void CClass1::Foo()
{
    Combo1.AddString(TEXT("text"));
}
```

Comment: Ok, I re-read the question and it's really not very clear.  You show only one dialog in the example code, but you talk about two dialogs in the question.

Comment: I have the main dialog and a second dialog. The second dialog is defined in CClass1. Sorry about the ambiguity of my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the strings to the combo box inside of [OnInitDialog()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwz35s59%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), which gets called automatically during DoModal():

In the header:

```
class CClass1 : public CDialog
{
    protected:
        virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
}
```

In the cpp file:

```
BOOL CClass1::OnInitDialog()
{
    __super::OnInitDialog();
    Combo1.AddString(TEXT("text"));  // or just call Foo() here if that's preferred

    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: It seemed pretty obvious at first so I tried it, but the class created by Visual Studio for the second dialog (the .cpp file) doesn't have such a function. When manually adding it, it gives me an error that says 'inherited member is not allowed'.

Comment: No, it inherits from CDialogEX.

Comment: Did you declare it like this in the header:  protected: virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();

Comment: @17 of 26 How would this function work for a third dialog created from the second dialog?

Comment: Should work the same.  The issue with MFC dialogs is that the controls don't exist until OnInitDialog() is called, so you need to do your initialization work there.

Comment: It gives me an error in the `if (CreateDlgIndirect(lpDialogTemplate, CWnd::FromHandle(hWndParent), hInst))` line of DoModal()

Answer (score 2):

The combobox window has not been created at the point you're calling foo(). You probably want to add a CStringArray member to CClass1, and then set it up to use DDX to load the combobox. The DDX step will happen AFTER the combobox window is created.

Here's a custom DDX function that does exactly this task:

```
void AFXAPI 
DDX_CBStringArray (CDataExchange* pDX, int nIDC, CStringArray& strings)
{
    HWND hWndCtrl = pDX->PrepareCtrl(nIDC);
    bool bMine = false;
    CComboBox* pCB = dynamic_cast<CComboBox*>(CWnd::FromHandlePermanent(hWndCtrl));
    if (!pCB)
    {
        pCB = new CComboBox;
        pCB->Attach(hWndCtrl);
        bMine = true;
    }
    if (pDX->m_bSaveAndValidate)
    {
        strings.RemoveAll();
        int nNumStrings = pCB->GetCount();
        CString strVal("");
        for (int x = 0; x < nNumStrings; ++x)
        {
            pCB->GetLBText(x, strVal);
            strings.Add(strVal);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        pCB->ResetContent();
        INT_PTR nSize = strings.GetSize();
        for (INT_PTR x = 0; x < nSize; ++x)
        {
            pCB->AddString(strings.GetAt(x));
        }
    }
    if (bMine)
    {
        pCB->Detach();
        delete pCB;
    }
}
```

You will add a CStringArray member to CClass1, and add a reference to this function in your DDX block. You add the strings you want in your ComboBox into the StringArray variable after you construct the class instance, but before you call DoModal(). This function will populate the combo box for you.

CClass1 is changed like so:

```
CClass1 : public CDialogEx
{
...
public:
    CStringArray myStringEntries;

...
protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support
...
};
```

Your DoDataExchange override will look like:

```
void CClass1::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    //{{AFX_DATA_MAP(CClass1)
    DDX_CBStringArray(pDX, IDC_COMBO1, myStringEntries);
    ...
    //}}AFX_DATA_MAP
}
```

Your calling class changes to:

```
CClass1 dlg(this);
dlg.myStringEntries.Add("Some text");
dlg.myStringEntries.Add("More text");
dlg.DoModal();
```

Or, alternatively, CClass1::foo() can be changed to populate the CStringArray:

```
void CClass1::Foo()
{
    myStringEntries.Add(TEXT("text"));
    myStringEntries.Add(TEXT("more text"));
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the ComboBox will have multiple strings and I want them to be loaded when I DoModal() the second dialog.

Comment: So a CStringList would make more sense, then. Let me edit and elaborate.

Comment: @AdrianMar You need to move the add string OUT of the dialogs constructor.

Comment: @johnathon It's not in the dialog's constructor. It's in a separate method.

Comment: @jwismar thank you for your effort, but the selected answer is a bit simpler. Again, I appreciate it!

Comment: @AdrianMar - no question, it's definitely simpler.  For a bit extra work up front, though, you will find it easier to extend and support your code, and to get the data back out after your dialog is closed, which is usually what you want to do.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Hey! i have one suggestion, there is a simpler way of passing the string from the first dialog to the second. You have already created an instance of the second dialog's class in the first dialog, now all you need to do is add a string member variable to the second dialog's class and initalize this variable with the combobox string before calling DoModal().

Answer (score 0):

When you refer to an `m_comboBox` in your `OnInitDialog` function you will get an error even if `m_comboBox` is present in the `DoDataExchange` definition.

You can solve this with two methods:

1. In your `OnInitDialog` you can refer to your combobox with

   CComboBox *cmb = (CComboBox *)GetDlgItem(IDC_YOURCOMBOBOX);
2. or call `UpdateData` before accessing `m_comboBox`, which will call the `DoDataExchange` function as explained in the remarks of [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/x4d0y489.aspx) about the `DoDataExchange` function.